# How can I move table contents between production and development?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have data living on the cloud in table storage and I would like to move this down to a development server.

I used to use Clumsy Leaf table explorer but I seem to often have problems where not all the data is moved. It gives an error half way through when I try to import data that I exported from the cloud.

Are there other options for me to move data between one location and another?

By the way I notice this question was asked before but that was in 2011 and the suggested made does not work. Please don't vote to close this as I hope that things changed since 2011.

Comment: Could you add a link to the other question? What is the error? Have you raised this with Clumsy Leaf?

Comment: Well there is no clear error message from Clumsy Leaf. I wish it did give an error but it just gives up !   I believe the problem is related to the way the data is stored. If there are some fields in for example record 100 that were not in record 1 when the first table was created then it gets upset and gives up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for other tools, may I suggest you look at Cerebrata tools (http://www.cerebrata.com). You could either use Cloud Storage Studio or Azure Management Cmdlets to download data from the cloud and upload in development storage.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am just wondering. Does Microsoft not provide any way to do this with powershell or cmdlets. It would seem to me that thing I am doing would be something that another 100,000 developers would want to do :-(

Comment: I expect there are 100,000 developers who would like to move their data to a storage account created after June!

Answer (score 0):

A while ago, I wrote a blog post about the different azure storage and service management tools. Most of the mentioned tools are still valid and they probably improved since I wrote the post. Check it out at http://gshahine.com/blog/archives/2010/11/04/azure-service-management-tools/